# What underlying table does SHOW PROFILES get the Query column from?

Tags: mariadb-10.4

I found that SHOW PROFILE gets data from the information_schema.PROFILING table. I'm trying to figure out what table SHOW PPROFILES is getting the Query column from.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The [information_schema.PROFILING](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-profiling-table/) contains the similar information in a table form.

Like all information_schema tables, they don't really exist as stored tables, they just expose system internals in table form.